# How can I tell Typescript that two object keys must be the same?

Tags: typescript

I want to define a type over a JS/TS record (i.e., something with keys and values):

```
type Args<R extends object> = {
  foo: keyof R
  bar: keyof R
}
```

How can I tell Typescript that I want `foo` and `bar` to be the *same* `keyof R`?

I can do this:

```
type Args<R extends object, K extends keyof R> = {
  foo: K
  bar: K
}
```

But then all clients of the `Args` type to have to manually specify type `K`:

```
type Pizza = {
  name:   string
  radius: int
}

const myArgs: Args<Pizza, 'name'> = { foo: 'name', bar: 'name' }
```

Typescript should be able to infer this, I would think. But how do I write the type?

Comment: What is `Pizza` ?, Please add minimal reproducible code.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with just a type alias because it would need to have the key as a generic parameter in order to enforce that.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible. You can create a union of all possible `foo` and `bar` combinations of a given generic type like this:

```
type Args<R extends object> = {
  [K in keyof R]: {
    foo: K,
    bar: K
  }
}[keyof R]
```

This will lead to the desired behaviour:

```
type Pizza = {
  name:   string
  radius: number
}

const myArgs1: Args<Pizza> = { 
  foo: 'name', 
  bar: 'name' 
}
const myArgs2: Args<Pizza> = { 
  foo: 'name', 
  bar: 'radius' 
} // Error: "name"' is not assignable to type '"radius"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-beta&ssl=16&ssc=114&pln=10&pc=1#code/FAFwngDgpgBAggJwOYGcA8AlGUAeIoB2AJijAPYBGAVlAMYgB8MAvDAN7AwwDaA0jAEsCMANZQwZAGYwMAXQBc7TlxiSyZRbwA0yrhQCGCTcoC%20wE9zETpc4HfDQYABQEAvV-pZKuBfQFsoRS4UEAQhJGUEfSIBAFcURQJYvwooBHM7WjICEJg-MERUAEZFQvQXd30mVjZVdUUAcl8Ahq0YAyMYJv8oBpgzLJyQPILkFAAmUrG0Co9q9jqNLubeto7GqJj4vpMYAHo9mABRBAQyToAiFYu%20gVICMmH9FBQBJF8KABtYEDIYB1gDQumziKAuwCAA)